# Looping and selecting active document

Tags: vba, ms-word

What I need to do is take a paragraph copy and paste it into a new file, save that file and then have it automatically do the same for the next paragraph. The code I have does this once. However, my document is 250 pages long with over 300 paragrpahs so I need this to automatically loop. Here is my code so far:

```
Sub clicktest()
    '
    ' clicktest Macro
    '
    '

    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=34, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=37
    Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument
    Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)

    Dim PathAndFileName As String, n As Long

    PathAndFileName = "\\r04brxnas20\VHABRXOSTROR$\Trace"
    If Dir(PathAndFileName & ".txt") = "" Then
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs (PathAndFileName & ".txt"), FileFormat:=wdFormatText
    Else
        n = 1
        Do While Dir(PathAndFileName & n & ".txt") <> ""
            n = n + 1
        Loop
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs PathAndFileName & n & ".txt"
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is to loop this and have the active document be the original so it selects the right paragraph automatically.

Comment: What's it doing now that is different from what you want it to do?

Comment: @eddie_cat from OP: *The code I have does this once. However, my document is 250 pages long with over 300 paragrpahs so I need this to automatically loop*.

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop over the `Paragraphs` collection should probably work.

Also, since it seems you are only concerned with creating plain text output files, there's no need to `Copy` or `Paste` anything and in fact there's no need to even use a new `Document`, all of this can be done with standard I/O statements.

Here is that approach, I have also tidied up the file naming convent & loop which had an error when I tried it.

```
Sub copyparagraphs2()
Dim pg As Paragraph
Dim doc As Document
Dim ff As Integer
Dim Path As String, n As Long
Dim filename As String

Path = "\\r04brxnas20\VHABRXOSTROR$\Trace\"

Set doc = ActiveDocument

'# Loop over the PARAGRAPHS in this document
For Each pg In doc.Paragraphs

    '# Construct a file path that doesn't already exist:
    Do While Not Dir(Path & n & ".txt") = ""
        n = n + 1
    Loop

    '# specify the filename
    filename = n & ".txt"

    '# Create the text file
    CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile (Path & filename)

    '# print the text to the text file
    ff = FreeFile
    Open Path & filename For Output As #ff
    Print #ff, pg.Range.Text
    Close ff

Next
End Sub
```

This avoids the need to worry about which Document is `Active` or `Selection` entirely.

Here is a related read on why to avoid Select/Activate whenever possible. It is written for Excel, where the `Selection` object is much easier to avoid using than it is in Word, but the same general principles apply.

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)